# how do i solve index error in linear search algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, index-error, linear-search

```
n = int(input("Enter size of array"))
num = int(input("Enter numbers"))
for i in range(0, n):
    num = int(input(hello.append(num)))
print(hello)
x = int(input("enter number to check!"))
count = 0
while count <= len(hello):
    if (hello[count]==x):
        print("found")
        break
    elif (hello[count]!=x):
        count = count + 1
    else:
        print("not found")
        break
```

Hello friends, I am a DSA Beginner and I got an error in my code on linear search. If I enter element which is present in list the code executes but if i enter element which is not present it gives me

> "if (hello[count]==x): Index Error: list index out of range"

help me out how my code can be efficient. TNX

Comment: The index starts at 0, that means the last index is one less than the length of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a length of a list it gives you the total number of elements in that list. But if you want element of that list with index as the total number of element then it will give out of range error.

For example :

$ l = [3,5,4,7,6]

$len(l)

5

$l[5]

IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if the number `x` is in list `hello` you should just do:

```
if x in hello:
    print('found')
else:
    print('not found')
```

Answer (score 0):

`count` should have a max value of `len(hello)-1`, since that's the last valid index for that array. Just modify the loop to:

```py
while count < len(hello):
    if (hello[count]==x):
        print("found")
        break
    else:
        count = count + 1
if count==len(hello):
    print("not found")
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code worked. But could you elaborate the 2nd if statement. what exactly happened in end. TYSM.

Comment: If the element was found, the loop would've broken and the value of ```count``` would've been lesser than ```len(list)```. If ```count``` did manage to reach that value, it means the loop never broke and the element was found